# How to make a timetable/ appointment system in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what I want:

[image]

It is like an appointment system/personal schedule. For example, a doctor have 4 periods of working time(sessions) everyday, and in each session he will have some patient to meet(the number in the table field). So His schedule look like the picture above.

At first thought, it looks like: Every `day` has many `sessions`. And a `session` contains some other information like the number of patients, etc. (and do not need to set its specific time period. )

The problem is how to set this up? I just have no clue about what the model should like. How should `Session` relates to `Time/Day`? And it seems `Day` and `Session` are already created.

I feel this could just be done with `Session` model, the model could contain some time attribute to sort them like the mock-up above.

I have checked some calender gem/plugin( e.g fullcalender), but they does not seem to help this problem.

Comment: My 2 cents is not use "session" as a model name which will introduce lots of confuse later.

Comment: Thanky, I have changed it to appointment when put into practice

Answer (score 0):

This could easily be done with a Sessions model with enough logic to enforce your rules. You will probably want to associate a Doctors model with a Patients model through Sessions, but I don't know enough about your needs to be sure.

You should review the [Rails Guide on ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for details on how to create associations and for ideas that may help you. One of the examples (2.4 The has_many :through Association) involves doctors and patients and is similar to what you describe.

Comment: Well, I might not be clear enough. The `appointment` does not relate to Doctor and patient. What I am looking for is more of how to sort the `Session` by some time attritube and its own sequence(session1/2/3/4). I think this should be done with just `session`, but have no idea about the sorting.

Comment: I'm not sure if I entirely understand but you could have a Session model with the attribute "date" and the attribute "block" where block is 1, 2, 3, or 4 corresponding to the session column you have in your table. Then when you need to sort, you can do so using those two attributes.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to use a `Date` attribute and a `Category` attribute.  It seems promising